# Finding alt attribute inside class

Tags: python, selenium, class, html-lists

I'm trying to extract in Python with Selenium the text inside this **img alt** attribute but I already tried a lot of stuff without success. The HTML is the following

[image: HTML]

I need to extract the yellow text. For what I just saw the main problem is the identification of the class "pull-right", if you notice it has a lot of **white space** between the class name " ". The driver **WebDriverWait(ScrapDriver,1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "pull-right")))** does not return nothing

Any suggestion on how can I get the text "Sotheby's Oeiras" ?  Also it's not possible to get this with xlpath because it has specific code and is not possible to generalize. xlPath is this:

**//*[@id="offer-item-ad_id11AHW"]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/img**

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does the xpath change every time? Are u 100% sure about it?

Comment: Hi Sushil, yes xlpath always changing with different ID, no chance :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following css selector to identify the element.

```
imgelement=WebDriverWait(ScrapDriver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[class^='pull-right']>img")))
print(imgelement.get_attribute("alt"))
```

OR

```
imgelement=WebDriverWait(ScrapDriver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.company-logo.lazy")))
print(imgelement.get_attribute("alt"))
```

---

Update you need to iterate.

```
imgelements=WebDriverWait(ScrapDriver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[class^='pull-right']>img")))
for imgelement in imgelements:
 print(imgelement.get_attribute("alt"))
```

Comment: Hi Kunduk, thanks for the quick answer, your answer solve half of the problem, yes now I can get the text I want, the problem is that I need to find all elements of this type, that's why I already try **WebDriverWait(ScrapDriver,1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[class^='pull-right']>img")))** and then print all elements with alt attributes but with no success. I tried this --> for alt in all_alt:
                    text=alt.text
                    print(text)

Comment: It worked this last option !!!! Life saver KunduK. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

To print them all do the following.

```
imgs=WebDriverWait(ScrapDriver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.company-logo.lazy")))
for img in imgs:
    print(img.get_attribute("alt"))
```